# How to declare a datetime type of variable in ssms

Tags: sql, datetime, variables, ssms

**this is the code i tried and i got some errors in it** I need to create a variable named createddate and use it in the another table.
[image: THE CODE I TRIED AND THE ERROR I GOT]

[image: THE FORMAT OF CREATEDDATE IS OF THE FOLLOWING]

Comment: Okay so what exactly should be the output and what error are you getting? How is it not working? What is the current result as opposed to the expected result? What input are you using for testing? Please provide us a bit more details to help us debug the problem without needing us to create tests, compile and run the code ourselves. If we have all the details it is much easier for us to help you. So please help us, help you.

Comment: Actually  what I want in my program  first is to when user enters list size less than 0 or greater than 21 then it should display invalid input and exit the program, and next when user enters input if he enters negative numbers it should display invalid input and exit the program. along with that if user enters only 4 inputs where 5 inputs are required then also it should give invalid input and exit the program.

Comment: make sure that is part of the question then and still how is it not doing that? Please give us an example input where the problem occurs. Make sure to [edit] the question with these details. Comments are not the place for new additions to the question

Comment: ok I edited that there is no place the question became bigger by elaborating it.

Answer (score 1):

> along with that if user enters only 4 inputs where 5 inputs are required then also it should give invalid input and exit the program.

Please provide a working example in which you can only enter 4 inputs to your program after defining the amount as 5. Do so without changing the way the inputs are aquired, and please also provide a step by step explantion how you are able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while n1 !=n2:` loop ensures, that user will have to enter the correct number of inputs. Otherwise he will not come out of loop. Is that not what you require?

Comment: No n2 has nothing to do with this. I just used it casually to check how many values i am taking. I have removed that part of the code.

Comment: Still, your loop guarantees that you will take n1 valid values. So user is still inputting correct number.

Comment: yes it has to exit if the n1 values are not given as input.

Comment: But that is happening already with your loop. So there is no way a user can provide invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code for you, please let me know is this u wanted ??

```
MIN_LENGTH = 0
MAX_LENGTH = 21

a = int(input('Total number of plots: '))

if a<MIN_LENGTH or a>MAX_LENGTH:
  print('Invalid Input')
  exit()

lst=[]
for i in range(a):
  ch = input(f'do you want to enter value for plot {i+1} (y/n)')
  if ch=='y': 
     value = int(input(f'Enter value for plot {i+1}: '))
     if value<0:
        print('Invalid Input')
        exit()
     lst.append(value)
  else:
     print('Invalid Input')
     exit() 
n =1  
for i in lst:
  print(f'plot:{n}= {i}')
  n+=1
```

Answer (score -1):

add below code after `n2+=1`

```
if n2>4:
    break
```

Comment: ok for n inputs then what about only 2 inputs given into list.

Comment: It means you want to decide at runtime how many inputs you want to enter into the list right??

Comment: yes it depends on the user if the user enters correct number of inputs it will be ok. if not then program has to terminate without any error.